# Generate invoice automatically when I create shipment?

Tags: invoice, shipment

I want to generate invoice automatically when I create the shipment for the order manually.
How can I create a system like this. Does anyone know how to do this? 
Any assistance will be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd go the route of creating an [event-observer](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method) for `sales_order_shipment_save_after`:

So in `app/code/local/Namespace/Module/etc/config.xml`:

```
...
<events>
    <sales_order_shipment_save_after>
    <observers>
        <namespace_module>
        <type>singleton</type>
        <class>Namespace_Module_Model_Observer</class>
        <method>autoInvoice</method>
        </namespace_module>
    </observers>
    </sales_order_shipment_save_after>
</events>
....
```

and in `app/code/local/Namespace/Module/Model/Observer.php`:

```
<?php
class Namespace_Module_Model_Observer
{
   public function autoInvoice($observer) {
       $shipment = $observer->getEvent()->getShipment();
       $order = $shipment->getOrder();
       if($order->canInvoice())
       {
           $invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareInvoice();
           $invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::CAPTURE_ONLINE);
           $invoice->register();
           $transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
           ->addObject($invoice)
           ->addObject($invoice->getOrder());
           $transactionSave->save();
       }
   }
}
```

Then you should be all set.

Comment: Very nice code, works perfectly for me as well. Can we also make it to capture the payment online automatically when invoice created?

Comment: Thanks @xxx, the code should be capturing your online payment `->setRequestedCaptureCase(...)` and the `transactionSave->save();`. Check your log files if this is not working for you.

Comment: Anyone trie on magento 2?